# Why can't a class's static variable be an instance of the class?

Tags: python, class, constructor, static

So I'm banging out a piece of code for funsies when I realize that I need a specific instance of a class to be available to all other instances.

Instead of making a global variable (which are, inherently, bad), I decided that I would make it a static member of the class. Here's an example:

```
class Node:
    nod = Node()
    def __init__(self):
        pass

n = Node()

print(n)
print(Node.nod)
```

This doesn't run! I get:

```
NameError: name 'Node' is not defined
```

What? Why can't I? I can do this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nod = Node()

n = Node()

print(n)
print(Node.nod)
```

And while I didn't include a stopping condition causing the code to recurse until `RecursionError`, the code still recognizes what a `Node()` constructor looks like.

Anybody want to chime in on this strange behavior?

Comment: `Node()` isn't defined until you define `Node()`. You are trying to use it in the place you are defining it.

Comment: Just move initialization out of class declaration and use this global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Node` needs to be defined before being used.

You can "fix" this like so:

```
class Node:
    nod = None
    def __init__(self):
        Node.nod = Node.nod or self

n = Node()   # you need this before accessing Node.nod

print(n)
print(Node.nod)
```

but is "smells" to me - why do you need the "instance" of Node - instead of using Node to hold properties to use.

Output:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x7ff22cd0c278>
<__main__.Node object at 0x7ff22cd0c278>
```